# How to pass variables between functional components in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { val } from './signup';
//import Header from './Header'
const url = 'http://localhost:80/form/api/index.php';
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fname: '',
      lname: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      cpassword: '',
      error: ''
    };
  }
  handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      fname: this.state.fname,
      lname: this.state.lname,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      confirm_password: this.state.cpassword
    };
    axios
      .post(url, user, {
        header: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!val ? <p>{val}</p> : <br></br>}
        <form action="#">
          <label>userName</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="fname"
            name="firstname"
            placeholder="Your name.."
            value={this.state.fname}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ fname: e.target.value })}
          />
          <label>Display Name</label>
          <input
            type=" text"
            id="lname"
            name="lastname"
            placeholder="Your last name.."
            value={this.state.lname}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ lname: e.target.value })}
          />
          <label>Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="athul"
            name="password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
          />
          <label>Confirm Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Re-Enter Password"
            id="confirm_password"
            autoComplete="hhhhh"
            name="confirm_password"
            value={this.state.cpassword}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ cpassword: e.target.value })}
          />

          <label>Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Your email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
          />
          <label>Message</label>
          <input
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e) => this.handleFormSubmit(e)}
            value="Submit"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

> Here i tried to use the "val" variable that is imported from Signup.js but for some reason on redirection it does not show anything

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const url = 'http://localhost:80/form/api/Signin.php';
var name = '';
var val = false;
class Signup extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      value: false
    };
  }
  sign = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    axios
      .post(url, user, { header: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({ value: result.data });
      });
    val = this.state.value;
    name = this.state.username;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.value ? (
          <form action="#">
            <label> Username</label>
            <input
              name="name"
              value={this.state.username}
              id="name"
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}
            />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              id="pass"
              name="pass"
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
            />
            <button onClick={(e) => this.sign(e)}>Signin</button>
            {name}
          </form>
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export { val };
export { name };
export default Signup;
```

> Here i exported the val variable along with the name variable On signing in of the user i need to show an extra component on the home page.

it is to check whether  a user has signed in or not

Comment: Are you simply trying to send some data with the `Redirect` that is rendered when `this.state.value` is truthy? Why not just imperatively navigate when the POST request resolves? `val` isn't part of any react component's lifecycle so it likely won't be the value you want it to be whenever a component gets around to rerendering.

Comment: i need to show a new component on a truthy value of state.value, I have not done the importing part of the value to app component.The idea is to show an extra component if a user has signed in.So the val is to check that.

Comment: So when `this.state.value` is truthy is the `Redirect` not working as expected? Or as I asked, are you trying to pass the value of `this.state.value` to the route/component rendering `App`?

Comment: yes i need to pass the value of  this.state.value to the app component

Comment: redirect is working fine all i need is to use the value of this.state.value in app to check the authentication of a user

Comment: Can you include the `Router` code that is rendering both `App` and `Signup`? Basically you just need to pass some route state along with the `Redirect` (or imperative navigation) and access it on the receiving route, or use some React context or global app state as baymax suggests.

Comment: i dont know how to do what baymax said i really did not go deep into redux concepts , i know to import and export global variables but thats all,dont know to change the state variables

Comment: Could you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces your issue for us to live debug in? I think all you need is to use route state to pass some data to the next page and unpack it on the receiving side.

Comment: thanks,learnt it and its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redux` to share state between components.

For example, to implement authentication you can define a state like `authState` which you can use on `App` component to check if user is authenticated or not. On `Signup` component, after `axios.post` you can dispatch an action to change `authState` value.

Comment: Maybe also suggest starting with the simpler React Context? React-redux is a bit heavy for just these couple values.